# how do i extract sharepoint files from the content database prefer c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

I am using SharePoint 2010 with a 2008R2 Content database.

I am trying to avoid downloading large files from SharePoint to PC only to move them onto the server for processing.

How can I extract files from content database directly?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you don't.

Directly interacting with a SharePoint content database will cause your SharePoint installation to lose Microsoft support.

Any interactions with SharePoint should be performed via the object model.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/841057/en-us

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a modification. I already run queries to extract user group information.

Comment: "Any read operations against the SharePoint databases that originate from queries, scripts, .dll files (and so on) that are not provided by the Microsoft SharePoint Development Team or by Microsoft SharePoint Support will be considered unsupported if they are identified as a barrier to the resolution of a Microsoft support engagement."